# Azure AD Quickstart says reply urls don't match the application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a quickstart for authenticating users with an asp.net core web app. I have created a new Azure AD with my VS subscription and added my application according to this [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp).

[image]

---

[image]

I have then changed my `appsettings.json` in the code to download in that quickstart as specified.

[image]

With this basically being the only items needing to be changed for the quickstart, I run the application from vscode and get the following:

[image]

Is there a way to view what the web app is sending as the `reply urls` in the request? Is there some other setting I'm missing that maybe isn't in the quickstart?

### Edit

As mentioned in the comments the query string property for **redirect_uri** has a value of `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3110%2Fsignin-oidc`or *`http://localhost:3110/signin-oidc`*.

I see this value in the `launchsettings.json`

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3110/",
      "sslPort": 44321
    }
  },
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "webApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3110/"      
    }
  }
```

If I change the value in the `profiles` object to the value indicated in the quickstart, it works after proceeding through the "unsafe" warning from the browser, but why is this not in the quickstart instructions?

Comment: it is weird ...I followed doc and run the project ,but seems everything works as excepted. Seems there is nothing wrong with your config . You can check reply url value on login page url in browser by param name : redirect_uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is because you are running your app with `dotnet run` command .

When the app is launched with `dotnet run`, the first profile with `"commandName": "Project"` is used. The value of `commandName` specifies the web server to launch .So that the `applicationUrl`(server URL) which is `http://localhost:3110/` is used .

If running app using vs , confirm the profile you are running with .

Comment: If I'm running with `F5` in VSCode is that calling the `dotnet run` command?

Comment: While this answer is not absolutely complete, it did lead me to the right answer. When I open the project in VS'17 and debug with my IISExpress profile it works as the "Quickstart" indicates that it should, and when running in VSCode the value of the `webApp` profile `applicationUrl` needs to be changed, unless I use the IISExpress extension.

Answer (score 0):

Its is important to check the `redirect_uri` parameter that is being supplied to the login endpoint. Its needs to match exactly to what has been registered in the portal.

Common issues include:-

- HTTP/HTTPS mismatch
- Port Number mismatch

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your answer isn't telling me what part of my configuration is causing the mismatch. I've followed all the steps in the quickstart and I don't see the issue.

Comment: I have told you exactly where the issue is likely to reside. I would suggest you go through the basic troubleshooting. Starting with the suggestion of checking your redirect_uri parameter. How you are starting your app is likely causing a mismatch of the URL Likely. Other than that I wish you luck